# XMPP / GTalk / Jabber library for windows phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, xmpp, google-talk

Does anyone know of xmpp (or GTalk, or Jabber) C# library for WP7? Good old jabber-net won't compile against WP7 runtime.

pom

Comment: Apparently there's no support for multi-tasking or background polling in the WP7 API. That may make things difficult.

Answer (score 3):

[Jabber.NET](http://code.google.com/p/jabber-net/) is using sockets, which are not supported on Windows Phone 7. Currently, there is no public implementation of the above mentioned protocols on Windows Phone 7.

Answer (score 3):

Windows Phone 7.1 SDK supports [sockets.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202874%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) however I have not tried to compile [Jabber.NET](http://code.google.com/p/jabber-net/) against the new SDK. Definitely worth a shot now that the SDK supports sockets.

Answer (score 3):

People from ag-software have created XMPP libraries for Windows Phone 7.

News about the first release supporting WP7  [MatriX development update](http://www.ag-software.de/2010/08/04/a-short-matrix-development-update/)

Download Page (s) [MatriX downloads](http://www.ag-software.de/matrix-xmpp-sdk/download/) and
[Download directory](http://www.ag-software.de/download-directory/)

If you use the given installer, there is section with information about the sockets which says:

> **MatriX SDK Readme**
>
> version:  1.4.0.1 released:   2011/04/14 Thank you for downloading our
> MatriX XMPP SDK for Windows Phone
>
> MatriX is a SDK for the extensible Messaging and Presence Protocol
> (XMPP) protocol written in c#. This SDK can be used to build high
> quality XMPP software applications.
>
> ..........
>
> **Windows Phone restrictions:**
>
> Windows Phone supports no sockets yet. Only HTTP WebRequests are
> available for communication with external servers. BOSH is an XMPP
> extensions for constraint clients to transport XMPP over the HTTP
> protocol. MatriX for Windows Phone is based on [BOSH](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0124.html) and can only
> connect to a BOSH conenction manager.

I hope this helps. BTW the installer version has a project sample ;-)
I just noticed that it's NOT free ^_^, there are more products [XMPP Libraries](http://xmpp.org/xmpp-software/libraries/) However they're offering free license for Open Source projects (see [License](http://www.ag-software.de/agsxmpp-sdk/license/))

Regards,
Herber